# How to use dynamic formControlName in Angular 4 and ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular4-forms

I am new to ionic and angular (or for that matter, to JavaScript too). I am trying to achieve dynamic forms in my messaging app where user will answer polls sent by the server. My HTML and TypeScript snippets are as follows.

```js
initForm() {

  // this.pollForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  //   question: '',
  //   options: '',
  //   polls: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createPoll() ])
  // });

  // let allPolls: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
  // for (let i = 0; i < this.messageList.length; i++){
  //   let formGroup = new FormGroup({});
  //   if (this.messageList[i].isPoll){
  //     formGroup.addControl(String(this.messageList[i].messageId), new FormControl(false));
  //     allPolls.push(formGroup);
  //   }

  this.pollForm = this.addNewPoll();
}

addNewPoll() {
  let formGroup = new FormGroup({});
  for (let i = 0; i < this.messageList.length; i++) {
    if (this.messageList[i].isPoll) {
      formGroup.addControl(String(this.messageList[i].messageId), new FormControl(true));
    }
  }
  return formGroup;
}

doSubmit(msg: Message) {
  // console.log(msg);
  // console.log(this.messageList[this.messageList.length-1]);
  // console.log(this.pollForm.get(String(msg.messageId)));
  // console.log(this.pollForm.get(String(this.messageList[this.messageList.length-1].messageId)));
  if (this.pollForm.get(String(msg.messageId)).touched) {
    console.log('Submitting form', this.pollForm.get(String(msg.messageId)).value);
    //this.pollAnswer = this.pollForm.value.options;
    msg.poll.isAnswered = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>

    <div class="message-wrap">
        
      <div *ngFor="let msg of messageList; let i = index"
            class="message"
            [class.left]="!(msg.fromUserId === currentUser.userId )"
            [class.right]=" msg.fromUserId === currentUser.userId ">
          <!-- <img class="user-img" [src]="msg.userAvatar" alt="" src="">
          <ion-spinner name="dots" *ngIf="msg.status === 'pending'"></ion-spinner> -->
          <div class="msg-detail">
              <div class="msg-info">
                  <p>
                      {{msg.fromUserId}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{msg.messageTime}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="msg-content">
                  <span class="triangle"></span>
                  <p class="line-breaker" *ngIf="!(msg.isImage) && !(msg.isPoll)">{{msg.messageContent}}</p>
                  <img *ngIf='msg.isImage && !msg.isPoll' class="line-breaker" src="{{msg.imageBase64}}">
                  <div *ngIf="msg.isPoll && msg.poll.pollType=='single'">

                    <form [formGroup]="pollForm">
                        <ion-list radio-group [formControlName]='msg.messageId'>

                          <ion-list-header>
                              {{msg.poll.pollQuestion}}
                              <div *ngIf='msg.poll.isAnswered'>
                              <br> <br>
                              {{pollAnswer}}
                            </div>
                          </ion-list-header>

                            <ion-item *ngFor='let option of msg.poll.pollOptions'>
                                <ion-label>{{option}}</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio [disabled]='msg.poll.isAnswered' 
                                checked="false" value={{option}}></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                            <button [disabled]='msg.poll.isAnswered' ion-button
                            block clear (click)='doSubmit(msg)'>Submit</button>
                          
                        </ion-list>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

messageList is being updated via mocks I created which is as follows

```js
import { MOCK_POLLS } from "./polls.mock";
import { Message } from "./../models/message.interface";
export const MOCK_MESSAGE : Message[] = [
    {
        messageId: Date.now(),
        messageContent: "Welcome to our app",
        messageTime: Date.now(),
        fromUserId: 4321,
        toUserId: 1234,
        isImage: false,
        isPoll: false
    },
    {
        messageId: Date.now()+10,
        messageTime: Date.now(),
        fromUserId: 4321,
        toUserId: 1234,
        isImage: false,
        isPoll: true,
        poll: MOCK_POLLS
    },
    {
        messageId: Date.now()+11,
        messageTime: Date.now(),
        fromUserId: 4321,
        toUserId: 1234,
        isImage: false,
        isPoll: true,
        poll: MOCK_POLLS
    },
]
```

```js
import { Poll } from './../models/poll.interface';

const MOCK_POLL_OPTIONS : string[] = [
    'Yes',
    'No',
    'No idea'
]

export const MOCK_POLLS : Poll = {
    pollId: 123456789,
    pollQuestion: "Do you like the current song?",
    pollOptions: MOCK_POLL_OPTIONS,
    isAnswered: false,
    pollType: 'single'
}
```

Output I am getting is as follows: 
[output image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygfN5.png)

[output image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdS3r.png)

The problem here is, whenever I press submit button of either of the forms, both the forms get submitted even though "if" condition in doSubmit() method is satisfied by only one and both the polls get isAnswered as true even though console.log in doSubmit prints correct value of msg passed to doSubmit method. Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: Where is the `msg` variable being set in your TypeScript? It almost feels like there's a missing `*ngFor`, where each `msg` in your HTML is a member of an array. I'm a bit confused by what you're expecting to differentiate with `msg.messageId`, since your example only shows a single formControl. Consider using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to quickly create an example that we could take a look at

Comment: @JackKoppa Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my code snippets.

Comment: It looks like I had already solved my problem of using multiple formControlName and was stuck because of exact same Mock messages. I just changed the mock messages and it is working exactly how I want it to.